# communicating arduino to the other Arduino using RF24 getting the wrong result

Tags: c++, arduino, communication, radio-transmission

I use these codes to transfer hello worlds but i just receive 
"&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&"
in the receiver.
I don't understand what is the problem.

*******************Transmitter code:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>

RF24 radio(7, 8);

const byte rxAddr[6] = "00001";

void setup()
{
  radio.begin();
  radio.setRetries(15, 15);
  radio.openWritingPipe(rxAddr);

  radio.stopListening();
}

void loop()
{
  const char text[] = "Hello World";
  radio.write(&text, sizeof(text));

  delay(1000);
}
```

*****************receiver code:

```
    #include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>

RF24 radio(7, 8);

const byte rxAddr[6] = "00001";

void setup()
{
  while (!Serial);
  Serial.begin(9600);

  radio.begin();
  radio.openReadingPipe(0, rxAddr);

  radio.startListening();
}

void loop()
{
  if (radio.available())
  {
    char text[32] = {0};
    radio.read(&text, sizeof(text));

    Serial.println(text);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the sending site you use:

const char text[] = "Hello World";
radio.write(&text, sizeof(text));

On the receiver site:
char text[32] = {0};
radio.read(&text, sizeof(text));

Are the both sizeof(text) equals?

In the sending part text is 11 bytes
In the receiving part text is 32 bytes